# Can we have a email button on left side of navigation bar of iphone application?

Tags: iphone, usability

My iphone application has email functionality. I want to place the email button on the left hand side of the navigation bar of the application. The application do not have "back" link, so i have space on left side of the navigation bar, to add email button.

I want to know, whether it is allowed by apple? as it is not the default behavior of the button at that location.

Answer (score 1):

That's allowed, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(createMail:)];

-(void)createMail:(id)sender
{
    //code here for mail functionallity.
}
```

Use this to solve your problem